# How to get my code dependencies from a conda env?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I wrote some Python code I would like to package to be easily installed from pip and conda.

The code runs in a conda environment containing all its dependencies.

For both pip and conda it seems that I need to write a `setup.py` file with a `install_requires` variable to set the dependencies. For pip I also need a requirement.txt with these dependencies.

`conda list --export` gives me a way to export the environment with everything including libraries, cython and ipython:

```
alabaster=0.7.3=py27_0
babel=1.3=py27_0
backports_abc=0.4=py27_0
cairo=1.12.18=3
cffi=0.9.2=py27_0
cython=0.23.4=py27_0
decorator=4.0.4=py27_0
docutils=0.12=py27_0
flake8=2.3.0=py27_0
fontconfig=2.11.1=3
...
```

but how can I get only the Python packages my code depends on? Shall I go through all my imports? In that case how would I manage the dependencies of the dependencies?